# Multi-Month View with different duration and dateIncrement / Prev Button triggers twice

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

In a custom view for summer and winter semester i tried to set a 7-month view with 6-month steps on clicking the prev/next buttons. (1 month overlapping)

```
duration:      { month: 7 },
dateIncrement: { month: 6 },
```

Next button works fine, but clicking the prev button triggers event loading twice.
On the first time the calender steps 6-month backwards the event loads again and shows the previous period.

I removed every part of the code, what could produce this behavior, but could't find out.

I tried to reproduce this without a ajax call, again next works fine and prev not:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/halmelar/pen/GRpoqpg?editors=0011)

Prev button shows the previous semester on the first click, but stops then.

Any ideas?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Could be a bug. Or it could be that it's just not intended to be used in this overlapping way. The issue will probably be internal to fullCalendar, not anything you've written.

Comment: Youre right, it seems to be a bug. Reported here:
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5319

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround for the bug, works fine:

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4678

```
header: {
        left: 'backButton,next today',
        center: 'title',                
},    
customButtons: {
        backButton: {
           click: function () {
                  calendar.incrementDate({ month: -6 });
           }
         }
    },
    bootstrapFontAwesome: {
         backButton: 'fa-chevron-left'
     },
```